# Iterating ArrayList inside a method

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a Candidades class that holds Candidate objects, as follow:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Candidates<Candidate> extends ArrayList<Candidate>  {

public int getTotalVotesCount()
{
    Iterator it = this.iterator();
    int i, total = 0;

    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        Candidate c = (Candidate)it.next();

        total += c.getVoteCount();
    }
    return total;
}
}
```

Class Candidate is as follows:

```
public class Candidate {

private int votes;
private String name;

public String getName()
{
    return this.name;
}

public int getVoteCount()
{
    return this.votes;
}

public void vote()
{
    votes++;
}

public Candidate(String _name)
{
    this.name = _name;
    this.votes = 0;
}
}
```

How do i iterate over it?

I know the code for the iteration is ok, as using the code outside the class works.

The test is bellow:

```
/**

 * @(#)Test.java
 *
 * Test application
 *
 * @author
 * @version 1.00 2011/3/8
 */
import java.util.*;
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Candidates candidates = new Candidates();

    candidates.add(new Candidate("One"));
    candidates.add(new Candidate("Two"));
    candidates.add(new Candidate("Three"));
    candidates.add(new Candidate("Four"));

    Iterator it = candidates.iterator();

    int i = 0;
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        i++;

        Candidate c = (Candidate)it.next();

        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            c.vote();
        }
    }

    int total = 0;
    it = candidates.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        Candidate c = (Candidate)it.next();
        total += c.getVoteCount();
    }

    System.out.printf("Votes: %d", total);
}
}
```

The code above correctly prints 14.

Comment: Why did you extend ArrayList for that?

Comment: what exactly is the problem? you can iterate over candidates as your main shows.

Comment: Because this is possible in C# (iterate within it own list), i'd like to know if it would be possible in Java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to iterate over a class from within the class, then use **this**:

```
for (Candidate c : this ) ...
```

Comment: Clear and concise.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to extend `ArrayList` (unless you think this may be more legible, or something else you didn't post about).

You can create an `ArrayList` of `Candidate`s and use `foreach` to iterate:

```
List<Candidate> candidates = new ArrayList<Candidate>();
candidates.add(new Candidate("One"));
candidates.add(new Candidate("Two"));
candidates.add(new Candidate("Three"));
candidates.add(new Candidate("Four"));

int total = 0;

foreach(Candidate c : candidates) {
    c.vote();
    total += c.getVoteCount();
}

System.out.printf("Votes: %d", total);
```

Comment: That was just an example (I'm learning java, coming from C#), and there will be more methods...

Answer (score 1):

I would make my Candidates class like this:

```
public class Candidates() {
  private List<Candidate> candidates = new ArrayList<Candidate>();

  public int getTotalVotesCount() {
   int total = 0;
   for (Candidate candidate : candidates) {
     total += candidate.getVoteCount();
   }
   return total;
  }
}
```

You still need to populate candidates but I would recommened using the foreach loop.

Comment: (im always a few minutes late to the party ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Don't extend `ArrayList`, implement `List`, and use [delegation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern), add your own methods. Also use [for-each](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) if you can.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still testing but I think it does the job

Answer (score 0):

`Candidates` isn't really a subtype of `ArrayList` - it's not a specialized generic container that extends the capabilities of `ArrayList`, it's just an `ArrayList` + convenience method for the specific type being stuck in there.

What I might do for this: `Candidate` class as you had, `Candidates` class a static helper class for convenient API:

```
public final class Candidates {
 private Candidates() {} //singleton enforcer
 public static int getTotalVotes(Iterable<Candidate> candidates) {
  //check for nulls
  int total = 0;
  for (Candidate c : candidates) total += c.getVoteCount();
  return total;
 }
 //other convenience methods
}
```

then, as others point out, use your collection of choice, and work with the code like:

```
Collection<Candidate> candidates = new //...whatever
// voting scheme
int totalvotes = Candidates.getTotalVotes(candidates);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Candidates<Candidate> extends ArrayList<Candidate>  {
```

This is a list with a type parameter **name** = Candidate (it's just a name and has nothing to do with the Candidate class)

```
public class Candidates extends ArrayList<Candidate>  {
```

This is a list of candidates.

I didn't read the complete problem and all the answers, but extending ArrayList is most likly not what you want to do. More likely you want to use composition rather than inheritance.