# Java - Iteration of ArrayList

Tags: java

I have a Class A

**CLASS A**

```
public ClassA {

ArrayList<ClassB> objB= new ArrayList<ClassB>();

 //getter and setter of objB

}
```

**CLASS B**

```
public classB {

int x;
int y;

private List<ClassC> objC= null;

//getter and setter of x,y and objC

}
```

**CLASS C**

```
public classC {

int a;
int b;

//getters and setters of a,b

}
```

I am storing a resultset in objB inside class A. I am trying to iterate objB in my service class.

> public Class serviceImpl{
>
> ClassA objA = new ClassA();
>
> **//here I need to get the values of variable x,y,a,b**
>
> }

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Please state more clearly what you want...

Comment: Show your code instead of describing it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterating ArrayList inside a method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236112/iterating-arraylist-inside-a-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use and [enhanced for-loop.](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20corejavatechtips%20%28Core%20Java%20Technologies%20Tech%20Tips%29)

Don't use classB instead of B in the generics. You got it right during the second edition.
Perhaps this can help you.

```
    ArrayList<B> classB = new ArrayList<B>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // instantiate the objects
    A myClassA = new A();
    B myClassB = new B();
    C myClassC1 = new C();
    C myClassC2 = new C();
    // set the values
    myClassC1.setA(1);
    myClassC1.setB(10);
    myClassC2.setA(2);
    myClassC2.setB(20);
    myClassB.setX(3);
    myClassB.setY(30);
    // create the lists
    List<C> myListC = new ArrayList<C>();
    myListC.add(myClassC1);
    myListC.add(myClassC2);
    // set the lists
    myClassB.setObjC(myListC);
    myClassA.classB.add(myClassB);// better use a getter/setter
    // iterate the list
    for (B auxClassB : myClassA.classB) {
        System.out.println("X:" + auxClassB.getX() + " Y:"
                + auxClassB.getY());
        for (C auxClassC : auxClassB.getObjC()) {
            System.out.println("A: "+  auxClassC.a + " B: "+ auxClassC.getB());
        }
    }
}
```

Console output

```
X:3 Y:30
A: 1 B: 10
A: 2 B: 20
```

Good luck

Comment: Before anyone asks, no this is not a link-only answer.

Comment: Today I learned that in Java the foreach iterator is called an "enhanced for loop", even though it is less useful than regular for loops.

Comment: I know that, i'm just wating the question to develop

Comment: Hi @PbxMan, I have updated my question, hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: aah, i got it, thanks for making me understand. Appreciate your help :). thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in class `A`:

```
for (ClassB b : classB)
{
    // whatever you want with b, which is of type ClassB
}
```

Comment: Class A is just a value object class which contains the arraylist object of class B and getters and setters. I need to get the content of Class B and C by creating object of class A in different class.